# If he uses a rifle…

Tags: grammar

Does this sentence in bold sound natural and grammatical to native speakers of English although I use “can” instead of “will be able to”?

A: Jack will try to kill that boar again tomorrow. He failed to kill it with a crossbow last time.

B: That beast is tough but not immortal. He needs to choose the right weapon. **If he uses a rifle, he can definitely kill it tomorrow.**

Comment: It sounds a little odd to me.  Is there some reason you don't want to use the conditional form of can which is "could"? I think it would be more appropriate TBH.  For example: *If he uses a rifle, he could definitely kill it tomorrow*.  Even though could has a sense of "might be able to", the addition of "definitely" makes it much more likely, with only a little room for doubt. It's a definite possibility.

Answer (score 2):

> That beast is tough but not immortal. He needs to choose the right weapon. If he uses a rifle, he **can definitely** kill it tomorrow.

If we remove "definitely" the sentence is totally fine even if the verb in the result-clause is "can".

It appears that in **American English** the auxiliary *will* is normally used with *definitely* for making predictions or assumptions in the future e.g. ”…he will (definitely) be able to kill it tomorrow”

[image]

Interestingly, according to Google Ngrams, **British English** forgoes *can*, preferring the *will definitely* form.

[image]